Error while downloading ev3dev onto my ev3 brick
I am trying to flash ev3dev onto my 32GB microSDHC card, using BalenaEtcher, but after flashing I get this error:

Something went wrong. If it is a compressed
image, please check that the archive is not
corrupted.
The writer process ended unexpectedly

Is this to do with the SD card or the image itself. On the ev3dev website, it says

The release can be a .img.zip or .img.xz; whichever you have will work with Etcher.

When I download it I get a zip file like this:
ev3dev-stretch-ev3-generic-2020-04-10.zip
 - ev3dev-stretch-ev3-generic-2020-04-10
  - ev3dev-stretch-ev3-generic-2020-04-10.img
  - .meta

Am I meant to flash the whole zip file,just the .img file or something else? I have tried both and they both cause this error. If I just plug the SD card in anyway, it just stays on the loading screen forever.
I am on Windows 11 (24h2)
If I press ctrl+shift+i and look at the console, the extended error message is:
index.js:2 Error: The writer process ended unexpectedly
    at i (index.js:353:5238)
    at t.createUserError (index.js:353:6464)
    at m (index.js:140:45502)
    at index.js:140:46208
    at L.<anonymous> (index.js:140:42787)
    at L.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at e.exports.H (index.js:2:2313625)
    at e.exports.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at index.js:2:2289445
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
2
index.js:2 Starting...
media/icon.png:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.js:2 Verifying 1 device, 99% at 5.70 MB/s (total 5.70 MB/s) eta in 0s with 0 failed devices
3
index.js:2 Amplitude Logger [Warn]: {code: 0, error: "Status 'unknown' provided for 2 events"}
index.js:2 CHILD: flash done 
Object
index.js:2 Flash results 
Object
index.js:2 Starting...
index.js:2 Amplitude Logger [Warn]: {code: 0, error: "Status 'unknown' provided for 2 events"}
index.js:2 Amplitude Logger [Warn]: {code: 0, error: "Status 'unknown' provided for 2 events"}
2
index.js:2 Amplitude Logger [Error]: Event rejected due to exceeded retry count


I thought we had a noticed about this on the ev3dev site, but apparently not. Etcher version high than v17 are broken. You can get the older release here: https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/tag/v1.17.0.

I am now using the older version of etcher, and now it gets to the "validating" phase. But once it gets to 2%, it stops, and raises and error; "Something went wrong while writing". Also, just before, the drive disappears from my file explorer, I guess disconnecting from my device. Is this a problem with my SD or another bit of software?

Ran it again, here is my stack trace from the console: rror: Error invoking remote method 'enable-screensaver': No handler registered for 'enable-screensaver'
at EventEmitter.i.invoke (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:57:526)
(anonymous) @ gui.js:37
3gui.js:37 Amplitude Logger [Error]: Event rejected due to exceeded retry count

It does sound like there could be something wrong with the microSD card itself or something unusual with the computer you are using.
